# How to keep any Window "Always on Top"?

Tags: windows, window-manager, always-on-top

Some software have an option for their window to be "Always on Top". Is there any way to get the same functionality for any window.
Let me give an example where this would be useful.

Suppose I have a small browser window with real time stats from a game. The window is automatically updated at the rate of once every 10 seconds. I would like the small window to be always on top. so that I can just look at it whenever I want to, without actually going to it and at the same time I could continue working in my main application, which is at full screen.

Is there any Windows hack or App which can give me this functionality?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: This is now obsolete!
<sub>Do remember the sub note of being cautious from my answer earlier.</sub>

---

**Always On Top Maker** -- `http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm`
<sub>It is always good to be cautious with singular applications like these.</sub>

Comment: got it to work in vista within 10 seconds :D, and its only 6k!

Comment: Ya, really good find.

Comment: problem with hotkey [AltGr+E] exits application but is also used to write "€"-character :-\ hotkey cannot be changed afaik

Comment: This link redirects to a car dealership site for me, can anyone else confirm?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [**PowerMenu**](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/)

[image]

- In addition to "Always on Top" it also gives you "Transparency" and "Minimize To Tray"
- Works with Win32 x86 (9x, ME, 2K XP, Vista, Win7)

Comment: +1, works under Win7 as well, been using it at work for quite a while. It has some issues, but is overall a rather stable product.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Virtua Win](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/), which is a virtual desktop manager for windows, and also provide Always on top.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AutoHotkey to set windows to always be on top. It was a nice surprise for me as well.

This will toggle Always On Top for the currently active window via the F7 key:

```
F7::
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle, A
```