# How can I cover parts of my screen while a certain task has focus?

Tags: windows

When I'm trying to learn some (sequential) information on a piece of paper by heart, I put a colored sheet of paper as a cover on it and pull it down line by line.

Now I'm searching for software that can do this functionality in Windows XP or Ubuntu, alternatively it could be a plugin for Chrome/Firefox/LibreOffice. Basically it would just need to be an intransparent window that is fixed in a certain location, but only while a specific task has focus, I want to be able to normally open other tabs or software applications.

I'm sure that something like this must exist, but somehow it is very hard to google for it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me a hint!

Comment: Why not just shrink the window height down so only one or two lines are visible at once?  I.E.: bring the bottom up so it covers what you don't want to see, and then use the scroll bar to bring it up into view as you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1:**

Move the window partly of the screen.

**Suggestion 2:**

Can't you just put *any* window there (best would be something non-disturbing like an empty Notepad window).
In addition, use some tool to keep that window always on top (see this superuser question for suggestions: [How to keep any Window "Always on Top"?](https://superuser.com/questions/19626/how-to-keep-any-window-always-on-top)) or a tool to be able to scroll any window under the mouse position and not only the active one (like [KatMouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/)).

If you don't want to install any tools, you could use *Windows Task Manager* (press ctrl-shift-esc to open it) which can be configured to stay always on top, so you can scroll the active window beneath.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the presentation software LibreOffice.  Just add one more line per slide. If you want to work with other apps just switch desktops via the keyboard shortcuts.