# Program to keep windows always on top

Tags: windows-7, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make window always on top?](https://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top)

I want a utility which will keep a window **always on top** even though that program has lost foucs. Program must have a global hotkey to keep that window on top. And I can focus on other windows keeping that windows on top.

OS: Windows 7

TIA

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make window always on top?](http://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top) and http://superuser.com/questions/19626/how-to-keep-any-window-always-on-top

Comment: @crucifiedsoul If you want a customizable global hotkey, see my answer here: http://superuser.com/a/371052/100787

Answer (score 3):

Check out [DeskPins](https://efotinis.neocities.org/deskpins/index.html). It should do what you are looking for.

> DeskPins can be used to make any application topmost, that is, to keep it above all other windows. Just grab a pin from the DeskPins icon in the system notification area and click on any window. This functionality is identical to the "Always on Top" setting found in some programs. With DeskPins you can add this feature to any program.

[image: DeskPins]

You mentioned a need for global hotkey feature. If the "pin" is not enough, try [Always on Top Maker](http://www.fadsoft.net/AlwaysOnTopMaker.htm).