# windows: how to prevent background programs from stealing focus?

Tags: windows, windows-10, window, focus, window-focus

please don't misunderstand me, i **do not** want a tool to make a selected window always stay on top - there's already plenty of answers on SU for that question ([such](https://superuser.com/questions/19626/how-to-keep-any-window-always-on-top), [as](https://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top), [these](https://superuser.com/questions/370893/program-to-keep-windows-always-on-top)).

what i want is that the currently active window be kept on top by default and that any new opening window open in the background, without interrupting my work. the issue i'm having is that if i open an application which takes a long time to load, then go back to whatever i was doing, the application will pop up on the screen after it has been loaded and steal focus form my active window.

i have searched for a solution for quite a while and found something that seemed to be promising ([link](https://superuser.com/a/404246/484475)) but unfortunately it caused a lot of side effects on my windows 10 computer (like not being able to search in the start menu, not being able to launch calculator and so on) while still not fixing the issue completely.

Comment: i might suggest a title change to (something like) keeping background programs from stealing focus, because that is totally different from "always on top".  Can i ask what program it is that would take so long to start running, that you could continue doing other tasks?  It is possible some AHK scripting could be used to keep it back.  Would minimise on run help with any of that?

Comment: various programs such as firefox, netbeans, matlab.. sometimes i use a BAT script to run multiple programs at once. sometimes it's some notification that pops up. thanks for the title suggestion, i will change it.