# Perfmon-type app with Always on Top feature

Tags: windows, debug

Does anyone know of a perfmon-type app, with nifty features, that can be selected with Always on Top?  I would like to view selected counters but need the window to be always visible, would help with some debugging on a two-monitor app.

Comment: you might like it better if you used the program you prefer most, and used one of the many utilities that can set a window to stick on top. That way you do not have to reconfigure another perfmon, and can stick "pin" or "stay on top" other windows on top using the same utility if needed later for other programs.

Comment: @Psycogeek, good idea, can you put this an answer, so I can select it?

Comment: it is a comment because it doesn't directly answer the question that is asked. it evades it :-)  Chances are good that there is a perfmon item that has on-top features.   Change the question, and it is a Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/28907/make-window-always-on-top  & http://superuser.com/questions/19626/how-to-keep-any-window-always-on-top